# Data Annotation for maximum age is greater than minimum age

Tags: .net, validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations

how to validate the Maximum Age should be greater than Minimum Age in Data annootation in mvc dot net?

i want to validate the maximum age is greater than minimum age using data anonotation in MVC dot net , when user enter the form

```
In my case , 

public class ModelForm 
{
    [Required]
    [Range(10,70,ErrorMesaage = "Enter the minimum age between 10 to 70 !" )] 
    public int MinAge {get;set;}


    [Required]
    [Compare("//Entered MinAge" , 80 , ErrorMessage = "Maximum Age Should be Greater than Minimum Age !" )]
    public int MaxAge {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Post your ViewModel class definition.

Comment: public class ModelForm { 


        [Range(10 , 70 , ErrorMessage = "Age should between 10 to 70 !" )]
        public int  MinAge { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Range( "//Entered [MinAge]" , 100 , ErrorMessage = "Error message"  )]
        public int MaxAge { get; set; }


        }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.